# The subring of $\mathbb Z$[x] denoted $\mathbb Z$[$x^2,x^3$]

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

My linear algebra notes reference subring of $\mathbb Z[x]$ denoted  $\mathbb Z[x^2,x^3]$ and I am confused what exactly this means. Is it the set of rings of coefficients of $x^2$ and $x^3$ separately under the normal operations of multiplication and addition? An example would be great to understand this further.

Edit: I am looking for this clarification is it the polynomials of the form

$\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_i((x^2)(x^3))^i$ ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the set of polynomials in $x^2, x^3$. So for example $5x^2+6x^2\cdot x^3+7(x^3)^3\cdot(x^2)^4\in\Bbb Z[x^2,x^3]$. In fact this is just

$$\{p(x)\in\Bbb Z[x] | a_1=0\}$$

i.e. polynomials with no linear term, since any higher power $n = 2k$ is just $x^n= (x^2)^k$ and $n= 2k+1$ gives $x^{2k+1} = x^{2k-2+3} = (x^2)^{k-1}\cdot x^3$. But you cannot get $x^1$ as a product of such things since degrees add, and you only have things of degree $0$ (constants) and then things of degree at least $2$.

Comment: Why can there not be a constant term take the first term to be $1(x^2)^0$ ?

Comment: I think you meant "no degree $1$ term" (as written is your equation $a_1 = 0$) instead of "no constant term".

Comment: @JoelCohen whoops, yes!

Comment: @JamesDickens see Joel's comment, it was a typo.

Answer (score 2):

Let $R$ be a commutative ring. Any polynomial in $R[x]$ can be written as $p(x^2)+xq(x^2)$. From this you deduce at once  the ring in question is the subring of $\mathbf Z[x]$ of polynomials which have no monomial  $cx$.